# zend framework issue with gdata api

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-gdata

i am using zend three legged php api to grab user gmail email. 
when first i run three-legged.php

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['ACCESS_TOKEN'])) {


if (!isset($_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'])) {
    // Get Request Token and redirect to Google
    $_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'] = serialize($consumer->getRequestToken(array('scope' => implode(' ', $THREE_LEGGED_SCOPES))));
    $consumer->redirect();
  } else {
    // Have Request Token already, Get Access Token
    $_SESSION['ACCESS_TOKEN'] = serialize($consumer->getAccessToken($_GET, unserialize($_SESSION['REQUEST_TOKEN'])));
    header('Location: ' . getCurrentUrl(false));
    exit;
  } 
} else {
  // Retrieve mail using Access Token
  $accessToken = unserialize($_SESSION['ACCESS_TOKEN']);
```

its working fine. 
but when i store **$accessToken** into a txt file. 
which has the following contents.

```
oauth_token=1%2FYJGLd0cfd1R9VpDlZtP2yiznfzgBLrKgT7dIwBaJgM0&oauth_token_secret=nmtJx45vUP6u1_5nIGPQbg1v
```

in other file i am getting this access_token and setting as under

```
$accessToken = new Zend_Oauth_Token_Access();
$accessToken->setToken('1%2FYJGLd0cfd1R9dfdsfVpDlZtP2yizngBLrKgT7dIwBaJgM0');
$accessToken->setTokenSecret('nmtJx45vUP6u1_5dfnIGPQ1v');
```

this is giving me the exception.

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Mail_Storage_Exception' with message 'cannot change folder, maybe it does not exist'
```

and other is

```
ext exception 'Zend_Mail_Storage_Exception' with message 'cannot select INBOX, is this a valid transport?
```

please help me how can resolve this.

Comment: how did you figured this out?